# in WPF, changing the colour of a bound row to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am pretty new to binding, and WPF in general.

Now I have created a DataGrid in my XAML view. I then created two DataGridTextColumns

```
DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        col1.Binding = new Binding("barcode");
```

I then add a the columns to the dataGrid. When I want to add a new item to the datagrid, I can just do,

```
dataGrid1.Items.Add(new MyData() { barcode = "barcode", name = "name" });
```

This is great and works fine (I know there are lots of ways to do this, but this is the most simple for me now).

However, the problem hits when I try to do the next thing;

I want to add these items to the dataGrid, but with different foreground colours depending on certain conditions. I.e -

```
if (aCondition)
  dataGrid.forgroundColour = blue;
  dataGrid.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: I would recommend you create as much as possible in XAMl, e.g. the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Triggers for example:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ACondition}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

For this to work your items of course need to have a property called `ACondition`.

**Edit:** An example (assumes that you might want to change the property at runtime and thus implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx))

```
public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _ACondition = false;
    public bool ACondition
    {
        get { return _ACondition; }
        set
        {
            if (_ACondition != value)
            {
                _ACondition = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ACondition");
            }
        }
    }

    //...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However could you give me an example of a property to work in this scenario (for the 'ACondition')

Comment: Added an example; Glad it helped :)